# How to access Index array in H5 file using jsfive library?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I need to grab the index array from an h5 file but can't seem to locate it.
I use this python code to print and see

```
import pandas as pd

ber_per_flow = pd.read_hdf('c:\\runbrowser\\data\\032266_1\\RunID032266_1.MonitorData.h5', 'count_of_reads_lengths')
print(ber_per_flow)
```

which returns

```
           All reads  Trimmed by adapter  Trimmed by quality  Trimmed by Adapter or Quality
12           2                 1.0                 1.0                            2.0
13           5                 4.0                 1.0                            5.0
14           5                 3.0                 2.0                            5.0
15           5                 3.0                 2.0                            5.0
16           9                 5.0                 4.0                            9.0
..         ...                 ...                 ...                            ...
459          1                 0.0                 0.0                            0.0
465          1                 0.0                 0.0                            0.0
466          1                 0.0                 0.0                            0.0
469          1                 0.0                 0.0                            0.0
476          1                 0.0                 0.0                            0.0
```

the first column starting at 12 and down is the index array.

This is my JS code

```
const readH5FileRLDataAsync = async (filepath, key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs_raw.readFile(filepath, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            else {
                try {
                    let f = new hdf5.File(data.buffer);
                    let keys1 = f.get(`${key}/block1_items`);
                    let group1 = f.get(`${key}/block1_values`);
                    let keys = f.get(`${key}/block0_items`);
                    let group = f.get(`${key}/block0_values`);
                    if (group !== undefined && group1 !== undefined) {
                        let result = splitIntoChunks(group, keys);
                        let result1 = splitIntoChunks(group1, keys1);
                        let merged = { ...result, ...result1 };
                        return resolve(merged);
                    }
                    else return resolve(null);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return reject(e);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

keys1 contains 'All reads', group contains the array for keys1, keys contains 'Trimmed by adapter,  Trimmed by quality,  Trimmed by Adapter or Quality' and group1 contains the arrays for corresponding keys. Neither contain the index array shown in python.

I'm new to this library, does anyone know how to locate <path_to_indexes_dataset> ?

Edit:
Console logging f.get(key) (which is the key I want to retrieve data from) I get

```
  "parent": {
    "parent": "[Circular]",
    "file": "[Circular]",
    "name": "/",
    "_links": {
      "BQ_per_flow_per_barcode": 12169031,
      "CE_dnn": 14077519,
      "CE_dnn_TT": 69343284,
      "CE_per_Ncopy": 14001567,
      "CE_per_Ncopy_TT": 69285900,
      "CE_per_Ncopy_constant": 14007263,
      "CE_per_Ncopy_constant_TT": 69296004,
      "EC_training_history": 1178374,
      "EC_training_statistics": 123654,
      "HG_amounts_per_flow_df_iteration_0": 3321454,
      "HG_amounts_per_flow_df_iteration_1": 3455757,
      "HG_amounts_per_flow_df_iteration_2": 3589212,
      "HG_count_of_reads_lengths_iteration_0": 1180686,
      "HG_count_of_reads_lengths_iteration_1": 3553356,
      "HG_count_of_reads_lengths_iteration_2": 3665747,
      "HG_hmer_counts_iteration_0": 3421205,
      "HG_hmer_counts_iteration_1": 3553916,
      "HG_hmer_counts_iteration_2": 3693027,
      "HG_hmer_counts_normalized_iteration_0": 3431309,
      "HG_hmer_counts_normalized_iteration_1": 3564020,
      "HG_hmer_counts_normalized_iteration_2": 3698731,
      "HG_negative_symbols_in_training": 3729299,
      "HG_pre_training_statistics": 1203190,
      "HG_training_data_general": 4784019,
      "HG_training_history": 4789723,
      "HG_training_num_of_iterations": 1190014,
      "HG_training_statistics": 2265070,
      "HG_trimming_df_iteration_0": 3437013,
      "HG_trimming_df_iteration_1": 3567740,
      "HG_trimming_df_iteration_2": 3704435,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_iteration_0": 3442709,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_iteration_1": 3576164,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_iteration_2": 3706035,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_normalized_iteration_0": 3448397,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_normalized_iteration_1": 3581852,
      "HG_very_high_hmer_normalized_iteration_2": 3716131,
      "MetaData": 6745064,
      "NPF_vs_Ncopy": 12223015,
      "NPF_vs_Ncopy_ratio": 12227911,
      "Ncopy_distirbution": 14012959,
      "Ncopy_distirbution_TT": 69301700,
      "Nexus_Plotting_path": 1024,
      "RLQ25.csv": 71835100,
      "RLQ30.csv": 71840804,
      "RSQ_hist_data": 10300951,
      "RSQ_hist_data_TT": 16342471,
      "RSQ_hist_data_configuration_0": 10097023,
      "RSQ_hist_data_configuration_1": 10102727,
      "SNR": 14097695,
      "SNR_TT": 69359292,
      "TT_fraction": 10278111,
      "TT_index": 6672920,
      "TT_ratio_hist_data": 10108431,
      "TT_threshold": 10116159,
      "Tandem_quality_to_plot": 69316588,
      "Tandem_summary": 14050967,
      "Tandem_summary_TT": 69320900,
      "Umap": 12134695,
      "after_offset_from_Tandem": 69316660,
      "alignment_rate": 12233919,
      "alignment_rate_TT": 67544780,
      "barcode_error_per_flow": 12139351,
      "barcode_error_per_flow_all_reads": 12145055,
      "barcode_error_per_flow_all_reads_weighted": 12149559,
      "barcode_population": 73896292,
      "barcode_population_variations_notshown": 73926892,
      "barcode_probability_of_error_per_flow": 12154351,
      "barcode_probability_of_error_per_flow_all_reads": 12160055,
      "barcode_probability_of_error_per_flow_weighted": 12164543,
      "barcode_rsqhist_aligned": 73065988,
      "barcode_rsqhist_nonaligned": 72235684,
      "base_flow_ratio": 10167783,
      "base_table": 10157679,
      "bc_bc_confusion_matrix": 10272399,
      "before_offset_from_Tandem": 14033551,
      "ber_per_flow": 71846508,
      "ber_per_read_hist": 71859948,
      "ber_summary_table": 72218788,
      "ber_summary_table_long": 72229980,
      "binned_class_error": 13414182,
      "binned_class_error_TT": 68717443,
      "class_error": 13881142,
      "class_error_TT": 69178123,
      "class_error_all": 13898542,
      "class_error_all_TT": 69195211,
      "class_error_different_RSQ": 13415782,
      "class_error_different_RSQ_TT": 68723139,
      "class_error_per_X": 13977039,
      "class_error_per_X_TT": 69274012,
      "count_num_of_nan_in_loss_training": 101558,
      "count_of_reads_lengths": 10193655,
      "count_of_reads_lengths_barcode_TT": 10216439,
      "count_of_reads_lengths_per_barcode": 10267743,
      "count_of_reads_lengths_summary_table": 10216999,
      "cycles_quality_change_before_after_Tandem": 69316732,
      "df_hmer_ranges_base": 13888438,
      "df_hmer_ranges_base_TT": 69189515,
      "dnn_density": 14079135,
      "dnn_density_TT": 69348996,
      "ec_df_cer": 33055799,
      "ec_df_motif": 66488452,
      "ecoli_systematic_threshold": 67543172,
      "eff_phasing": 71797300,
      "existing_barcodes": 6761379,
      "flow_error": 13934334,
      "flow_error_TT": 69231307,
      "flow_order_with_respect_to_true_key": 12328566,
      "flow_order_with_respect_to_true_key_TT": 67650299,
      "hmer_base_error": 13886838,
      "hmer_base_error_TT": 69183819,
      "hmer_count_per_base": 13904238,
      "hmer_count_per_base_TT": 69200907,
      "hmer_counts_normalized": 13915630,
      "hmer_counts_normalized_TT": 69212299,
      "hmer_regressed_normalized": 13921334,
      "hmer_regressed_normalized_TT": 69213907,
      "linearity_signal": 14091991,
      "linearity_signal_TT": 69357684,
      "max_barcodes_to_plot": 99246,
      "mean_qual_change_after_tandem": 14026231,
      "mean_qual_change_after_tandem_TT": 69314972,
      "median_hmerflow": 71621684,
      "median_hmerflow_raw": 71527068,
      "medians_per-xloc": 71614876,
      "min_short_read_percentage": 110790,
      "monitor_set_size": 712,
      "motif_class_error_1_base": 13408486,
      "motif_class_error_1_base_TT": 68711747,
      "neighbor_out_of_range": 14071807,
      "neighbor_out_of_range_TT": 69333172,
      "no_nearest_neighbor_percentage": 14061695,
      "no_nearest_neighbor_percentage_TT": 69331556,
      "nof_pcr_errors": 13397422,
      "nof_pcr_errors_TT": 68700995,
      "number_of_beads_per_X": 13993023,
      "number_of_rsq_configurations": 7824859,
      "pcr_probability_plot": 68700923,
      "percentage_of_aligner_output_of_data": 10121871,
      "percentage_of_beads_failed_RSQ_passed_barcode": 10127583,
      "percentage_of_failed_reads_from_burned_tiles": 10091311,
      "percentage_of_failed_reads_from_burned_tiles_TT": 16336759,
      "photo_dict": 78133132,
      "polyclonal_Total_Estimate": 10283823,
      "polyclonal_Total_Measure": 10289535,
      "polyclonal_fraction": 10305399,
      "polyclonal_fraction_passed_RSQ": 10321223,
      "polyclonal_results_for_LibMD": 10295247,
      "quality_RSQ_filter": 10133295,
      "quality_around_tandem_15": 14020527,
      "quality_around_tandem_15_TT": 69309268,
      "reads_counting_data_failed_quality": 10144631,
      "reads_counting_data_failed_reads_length": 10150999,
      "reads_counting_data_passed_quality": 10138263,
      "rsq_per_barcode_configuration": 6774235,
      "rsq_thresh": 10137871,
      "saturation_fractions": 71477604,
      "save_data_flag": 69373380,
      "signal_per_flow": 71509348,
      "std_hmerflow": 71709492,
      "tile_median_errors": 72218228,
      "trimming_data": 12246335,
      "trimming_data_TT": 67557196,
      "trimming_data_stat": 12326966,
      "trimming_data_stat_TT": 67637827,
      "undetermined_fraction": 10315511,
      "undetermined_fraction_passed_RSQ": 10326935,
      "very_high_hmer": 13909942,
      "very_high_hmer_TT": 69206611,
      "very_high_hmer_normalized": 13927038,
      "very_high_hmer_normalized_TT": 69224011,
      "wafer_class_error_cv": 13421814,
      "wafer_density_cv": 14099303,
      "wafer_map_class_error": 13876486,
      "wafer_map_class_error_TT": 69173467,
      "wafer_map_density": 8286971,
      "wafer_map_density_TT": 14099375,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq": 8296763,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq_TT": 15002239,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq_barcode": 9202011,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq_barcode_TT": 15002871,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq_barcode_alignment": 9208283,
      "wafer_map_passed_rsq_barcode_alignment_TT": 15905735,
      "wafer_map_rsq": 10021703,
      "wafer_map_rsq_TT": 16267159,
      "wafer_passed_rsq_and_bc_and_aligned_cv": 15455327,
      "wafer_passed_rsq_and_bc_cv": 15002799,
      "wafer_passed_rsq_cv": 14551831,
      "wafer_rsq_cv": 9664891,
      "wafer_rsq_cv_TT": 15910391,
      "wafer_uniformity": 71804668,
      "wafer_uniformity_summary": 71829404
    },
    "_dataobjects": {
      "fh": {},
      "msgs": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
      ],
      "msg_data": {},
      "offset": 96,
      "_global_heaps": {},
      "_header": {},
      "_filter_pipeline": null,
      "_chunk_params_set": false,
      "_chunks": null,
      "_chunk_dims": null,
      "_chunk_address": null
    },
    "_attrs": null,
    "_keys": null,
    "_fh": "[Circular]",
    "filename": "",
    "mode": "r",
    "userblock_size": 0
  },
  "file": "[Circular]",
  "name": "/count_of_reads_lengths",
  "_links": {
    "axis0": 10174167,
    "axis1": 10175087,
    "block0_items": 10170087,
    "block0_values": 10169591,
    "block1_items": 10171047,
    "block1_values": 10170559
  },
  "_dataobjects": {
    "fh": "[Circular]",
    "msgs": [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "msg_data": {},
    "offset": 10193655,
    "_global_heaps": {},
    "_header": {},
    "_filter_pipeline": null,
    "_chunk_params_set": false,
    "_chunks": null,
    "_chunk_dims": null,
    "_chunk_address": null
  },
  "_attrs": null,
  "_keys": null
}
```

Not too sure how this works because I see block0_values: 10169591 yet if you console log it you get this

```
name: '/count_of_reads_lengths/block0_values',
  _dataobjects: DataObjects {
    fh: ArrayBuffer {
      [Uint8Contents]: <89 48 44 46 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 00 00 08 08 00 04 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff a9 58 25 07 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a8 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 06 00 ... 119887941 more bytes>,
      byteLength: 119888041
    },
    msgs: [
      [Map], [Map], [Map],
      [Map], [Map], [Map],
      [Map], [Map], [Map],
      [Map]
    ],
    msg_data: ArrayBuffer {
      [Uint8Contents]: <01 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 bf 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 bf 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 18 00 01 00 00 00 11 20 3f 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 34 0b 00 34 ff 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 08 00 01 00 00 00 02 02 02 01 00 00 00 00 08 00 18 00 ... 292 more bytes>,
      byteLength: 392
    },
    offset: 10169591,
    _global_heaps: {},
    _header: Map(6) {
      'version' => 1,
      'reserved' => 0,
      'total_header_messages' => 10,
      'object_reference_count' => 1,
      'object_header_size' => 392,
      'padding' => 0
    },
    _filter_pipeline: null,
    _chunk_params_set: false,
    _chunks: null,
    _chunk_dims: null,
    _chunk_address: null
  },
  _attrs: null,
  _astype: null
]
```

if you do group.shape it contains the array that we see in python (just for 'all reads'), but I don't see 'shape' property in the console log.